# How to import csv file to mssql express server in C# and changing datatypes

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I've got a console application that uses an API to get data which is then saved into a csv file in the following format:

Headers:
`TicketID,TicketTitle,TicketStatus,CustomerName,TechnicianFullName,TicketResolvedDate`

Body:
String values. where `TicketResolvedDate` is written as: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`

Now I want to import this csv file into my mssql express database using the same console application and make sure the `TicketID` is imported as a integer datatype and the `TicketResolvedDate` as a SQL datetime datatype.

I've made the following code:

```cs
List<TicketCSV> tickets = new List<TicketCSV>();

using var reader1 = new StreamReader(OutputClosedTickets);
using var reader2 = new StreamReader(OutputWorkhours);

using var csv1 = new CsvReader((IParser)reader1);
{
    csv1.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
    csv1.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
    csv1.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) => header.ToLower();

    csv1.ReadHeader();
    while (csv1.Read())
    {
        var record = new TicketCSV
        {
            TicketID = csv1.GetField<int>("TicketID"),
            TicketTitle = csv1.GetField("TicketTitle"),
            TicketStatus = csv1.GetField("TicketStatus"),
            CustomerName = csv1.GetField("CustomerName"),
            TechnicianFullName = csv1.GetField("TechnicianFullName"),
            TicketResolvedDate = SqlDateTime.Parse(csv1.GetField("TicketResolvedDate"))

        };
        tickets.Add(record);

    }
}

using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "GeslotenTickets";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer((IDataReader)csv1);

    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "WerkUren";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer((IDataReader)reader2);
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is remotely near the idea i should have to establish this

Comment: Create and execute a stored procedure

Comment: This stored procedure will execute an INSERT statement

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE BlaBlaBla @@TicketID  INT ...

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE BlaBlaBla @TicketID INT ... INSERT TargetTableInser (TicketID,  ...) VALUES (@TicketID ,  ...)

Comment: Within SP for data type changing you use CAST. Please.

Comment: If you interested I can propose code which will insert this bunch of data in two lines. What is important for SQL server is the CASE of column names.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the idea is to use the already existing console application to execute this. So to work from console app ->csv file -> sql database and not from sql database -> csv file

Comment: I think you can create a datatable and populate it by your CSV reading and then use bulk import to import data from that table. See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-insert-in-sql-server-from-c-sharp

Comment: It will be the same console application but with simple line `db.BulkCopy(tickets)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are a couple issues with your code. You're reading the CSV data into objects, but then passing the CsvReader to the bulk copy operation. At that point all the CSV data in the reader has already been consumed, because you read it all when you were creating objects. Thus the SqlBulkCopy won't see any data in the reader.

The next issue that I think you're going to have is that the "schema" of the data reader needs to match the schema of the target SQL table. If the schemas don't match, you'll typically get some cryptic error message out of the SqlBulkCopy operation, that some type can't be converted.

I maintain a library that I've specifically designed to work well in this scenario: [Sylvan.Data.Csv](https://github.com/markpflug/Sylvan). It allows you to apply a schema to the "untyped" CSV data.

Here is an example of how you could write CSV data to a table in SqlServer:

```cs
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

static void LoadTableCsv(SqlConnection conn, string tableName, string csvFile)
{

    // read the column schema of the target table
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = $"select top 0 * from {tableName}"; // beware of sql injection
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    var colSchema = reader.GetColumnSchema();
    reader.Close();

    // apply the column schema to the csv reader.
    var csvSchema = new CsvSchema(colSchema);
    var csvOpts = new CsvDataReaderOptions { Schema = csvSchema };
    using var csv = CsvDataReader.Create(csvFile, csvOpts);

    using var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
    bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(csv);
}
```

You still might encounter errors if the CSV data doesn't correctly match the schema, or has invalid or broken records, but this should work if your csv files are clean and valid.

Comment: I tried your code example, but i get a exception that the connection is closed and not open

Comment: The expectation wass that you are passing an already-opened SqlConnection to the function.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't :P But fixed it within the loadtablecsv. Think thats a saver option for the connection. Do you by any chance also know how i can put something like the following code in the C# commands? WITH cte AS  
( SELECT Id, Name, Location, Gender, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Location, Gender  
ORDER BY Name, Location, Gender) row_num FROM table1  
)  
DELETE FROM cte WHERE row_num > 1;

Comment: MarkPflug, what would i need to use from your package if i don't want to bulkcopy, but only import the rows that don't exist yet?

Comment: Posted and answer on your new question.